# Button marked after initialization - how to avoid this?

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 app with JS views. I have a problem regarding the footer of my detail page - I created a button there and after initialization it is marked in the browser. I am not sure whether this is a Google Chrome problem or something with my coding. The code is not complex, so I dont know where to search for the origin.

Code and image of the problem:

[image: Button is marked]

```html
<Bar>
  <contentLeft>
 <Image src="./images/image1.jpg" height="80%" />
  </contentLeft>
  <contentRight>
  <Button icon="sap-icon://action-settings" press="handleSettingsButtonPressed" />
  </contentRight>
</Bar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you see is the visualization of the focus and as such helping users to navigate with keyboard-only. You didn't paste a lot of context for the code, but if there is a NavContainer/App control around, it automatically focuses the first focusable control in each displayed page (this will be made more flexible soon).

Of course you could remove the focus by calling blur() on document.activeElement, but I'm not sure this is the best thing for users...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with akudev's answer on this. What you are seeing is the focus indicator showing that button currently has focus. Presumably you want something to have initial focus, but it's not 100% clear from the question what you'd like to be different.

If you want the focus indication to look different you can modify that (or even eliminate it entirely) using CSS. Eliminating it entirely is probably going to make it harder for the user to know what's going on.

If you want a different element of the dialog to get initial focus you can use the initialFocus association to set the desired element.

Comment: Valuable hint! In my XML view, however, I have no element which admits an "initialFocus" attribute. The page has an active nav button, and the focus is automatically set to that nav button. I am trying to overwrite the "getDomRef" function for the Page now, it seems to be the recommended way to put the focus on another element than the default one chosen by SAP).